# java inheritence on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance

I am learning inheritance and while doing so on Eclipse, I get an error when trying to run the following program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class singinh
{
    void sub(int a, int b)
    {
        int c = a-b;
        System.out.println("Diff is"+c);
    }
}
public class singinh1 extends singinh {
    int a,b;
    void add(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
        System.out.println("Sum is"+a+b);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        singinh1 s = new singinh1();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        s. add(a,b);
        s.sub(a,b);
    }
}
```

The error that I get is "Error: Could not find or load main class superex$A";  What is causing this error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is the name if this java file? Also note that one .java file can have only 1 public class whose name must match the name of the file

Comment: Java looks for classes based on file names, not the contents of the files. I am assuming youve named that file singinh1, but no singinh file exists so the class laoder cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java you cannot have more than one public class in the same source file. Also the name of the source file should be the name of the public class in that source file exactly.

Since your main method is in "singinh1" class , keep it as the public class and remove public keyword from "singinh" class. Name the source file name to 
singinh1.java .

Modified code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class singinh
{
    void sub(int a, int b)
    {
        int c = a-b;
        System.out.println("Diff is"+c);
    }
}

public class singinh1 extends singinh {
    int a,b;
    void add(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
        System.out.println("Sum is"+a+b);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        singinh1 s = new singinh1();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        s. add(a,b);
        s.sub(a,b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you start with `java` the best thing to do is to create 2 files `singinh.java` and `singinh1.java`, move the related code into the corresponding file and launch your `java` command using `singinh1` as main class.

In `singinh.java` you will have:

```
public class singinh
{
    void sub(int a, int b)
    {
        int c = a-b;
        System.out.println("Diff is"+c);
    }
}
```

In `singinh1.java` you will have:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class singinh1 extends singinh {
    int a,b;
    void add(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
        System.out.println("Sum is"+a+b);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        singinh1 s = new singinh1();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        s. add(a,b);
        s.sub(a,b);
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to launch `singinh1`